# Is there a way to track GPS localisation even with the app killed or in background? Flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, gps

I want to make a Flutter app which gets the current localisation of the users, but I wanna know if this is possible even when the app is killed.

If this is possible, Apple authorises it normally or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is possible now with isolates. It's a bit advanced to implement, but here is a medium article explaining a geofencing plugin for Flutter.
https://medium.com/flutter/executing-dart-in-the-background-with-flutter-plugins-and-geofencing-2b3e40a1a124